# How can I get an alternate stylesheet to load into wp_head when saving/resetting a theme options page?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I was hoping I could get some help on how to load two different embedded stylesheets into the head tag (wp_head action hook), depending on if a user clicks save or reset in a theme options page.

The way it is set up now, only the options specified in the array at the beginning (the options typed in by the user) are saved, but not the alternative stylesheet. Right now I have placeholder functions called test1() and test2() in the place of the actual stylesheets that would be loaded into wp_head. Below is the code I have. The parts that are commented out below the test functions are what I tried to get this functionality to work.

```
<?php // add the admin options page
$themename = "Cool Orange";
$shortname = "co";
$options = array (
array ( "name" => "Main Settings",
    "type" => "title" ),

array ( "type" => "open" ),

array ( "name" => "Upload logo to the Media Library:",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo_label",
    "std" => "",
    "type" => "label" ),

array ( "name" => "Logo location:",
    "desc" => "In this section, you can replace the standard blog title heading with a custom logo. The logo cannot be wider than 960 pixels.",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo_url",
    "std" => "",
    "type" => "text" ),

array ( "name" => "Logo width:",
    "desc" => "Enter logo width in pixels, for example <strong>800px</strong>",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo_width",
    "std" => "",
    "type" => "text" ),

array ( "name" => "Logo height:",
    "desc" => "Enter logo height in pixels, for example <strong>90px</strong>",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo_height",
    "std" => "",
    "type" => "text" ),

array( "type" => "close" )

);

function mytheme_add_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach($options as $value) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }
            foreach ($options as $value) {
        if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }
        header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
        die;
        } else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach ($options as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] ); }
            header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
            die;
        }
    }
    add_theme_page($themename." Options", "".$themename." Options", 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');
}

function mytheme_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
    if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>'; ?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2><?php echo $themename; ?> Theme Options</h2>

<form method="post">
    <h3>How to upload a logo to replace the heading</h3>
    <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #BBBBBB; padding: 30px;">
    <ul style="list-style: disc;">
    <li>Upload the image from your computer to the Media Library using the <strong>Upload image</strong> button below</li>
    <li>Go to the <strong>Media</strong> button at the left to acces the Media Library. Look for the file you just uploaded. It should be the file at the top of the list.</li>
    <li>Once you mouseover the image, click <strong>Edit</strong></li>
    <li>in the Edit Media dialog, highlight (Ctrl a) the url in the <strong>File URL</strong> textbox</li>
    <li>Note the width and height of the image</li>
    <li><strong>Copy</strong> (ctrl c) the url and return to this page by clicking <strong>Appearance</strong>, then <strong>Cool Orange Theme Options</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Paste</strong> (ctrl v) the url into the <strong>Logo location</strong> box below</li>
    <li><strong>Paste</strong> (ctrl v) the width and height of the image into the <strong>Logo width</strong> and <strong>Logo height</strong> boxes below</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<?php foreach($options as $value) {
//Next is the code which tells WordPress how to display the ‘type’ of option used (title, open, close, text, textarea, checkbox etc.)

switch ( $value['type'] ) {
    case "open":
    ?>
    <div style="width: 100%;">
    <?php break;
    case "title":
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
    <?php break;
    case "label":
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $value['name']; ?></p>
    <p><label for="upload_image">
    <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload image" /></p>
    <?php break;
    case "text":
    ?>
    <p><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></p>
    <input style="width:400px;" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo get_settings( $value['id'] ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" /><br />
    <div style="font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></div>
    <?php break;
    case "close":
    ?>
    </div><br />
    <?php break;
    }
} ?>
<p class="submit">
<input name="save" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
</p>
</form>
<form method="post">
<p class="submit">
<input name="reset" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Reset" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
</p>
</form>

</div> 
<?php 
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin'); 

//Scripts to load WP's Media Library panel
//http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

function my_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_register_script('my-upload', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri()).'scripts/invoke_uploader.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
}

function my_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'functions.php') {
    add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');
    add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_styles');
}

//test functions
function test1() { 
echo '<!-- logo stylesheet -->';
}

function test2() {
echo '<!-- reset stylesheet -->';
}

//if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) {
//      add_action('wp_head', 'test1');
//} elseif ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) {
//      add_action('wp_head', 'test2');
//}

?>
```

I'm open to alternative ways of doing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after only two days of trial and error, I found a solution, or rather, a workaround to this problem. I followed a tutorial on how to switch stylesheets from within a theme options page. The tutorial is called [Add a Style Switcher to your WordPress Theme](http://fearlessflyer.com/2009/12/add-a-style-switcher-to-your-wordpress-theme/). In this tutorial the author switches external stylesheets from a selection drop down menu. In my code, I swapped out the external stylesheets for embedded stylesheets. In the case of my question above, that would be the test1 and test2 functions.

A code example would be:

Add a new array at the top

```
array ( "name" => "Restore CSS",
    "desc" => "Restore the original heading text",
    "id" => $shortname."_restore_css",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array ("select an option", "test2"),
    "std" => "Logo CSS" ),
```

Then add a new function, in this case called css_switcher

```
function css_switcher() { //opens css_switcher function

global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
}

?>
<!-- logo stylesheet goes outside of switch statement -->
<?php switch ($co_restore_css) {//opens switch statement
case "select an option": //nothing goes between this closing php tag and
                         // next opening php tag, to make select an option do nothing 
?>
<?php break;
case "Restore CSS": ?>
<!-- restore stylesheet goes inside of switch statement -->
<?php break; 
}//closes switch statement

}//closes css_switcher_function

add_action('wp_head', 'css_switcher');
?>
```

This worked for me.